# Apigee token management and username/password OAuth authentication

Tags: oauth, apigee

I have a question about delegating token management:

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/authorize-requests-using-oauth-20#delegating-token-management

Does this mean that Apigee Edge will generate the token, and it is only the storage that is delegated?

What feature could I use if I want my own external system to perform the username/password authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. Apigee will generate the token; you'll store it.

For the authorization grant types that require username/password authentication of the app end user, you always perform the user authentication via an external system.

You can see an example of password authentication in an OAuth flow in this sample on github:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/oauth-login-app

Comment: Thanks. I don't see code/configuration to call to perform the user authentication via an external system in this example, could you point it out?

Comment: @mparaz Check out http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/call-services-or-apis-using-servicecallout.  That's the policy information to make a 3rd party callout which can be used for the external user authentication.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the callout policy. Where can I find out how to make the callout for authentication?